# Автоматическая realtime блокировка ip с помощью nginx

Tags: nginx

В [senginx](http://www.senginx.org/en/index.php/Main_Page) есть дефолтный модуль *Dynamic IP Blacklist*, он позволяет вносить *IP-адреса* ботов или сканеров в черный список в режиме реального времени автоматически. Прекрасный функционал, но насколько я понял, он жестко завязан на других встроенных модулях, что сильно ограничивает рамки его использования.

Существует ли альтернатива, дающая более гибкие возможности срабатывания, например  блокировать *ip-адрес* сразу при попадании "пользователя" в определенный `location` *nginx*, или при превышении заданных параметров `limit_conn_zone` / `limit_req_zone`?

Раньше на Апаче помогал костыль со скриптом записывающем адрес в `.htaccess`.
Как сделать **грамотно** нечто подобное на *nginx+php* — ума не приложу...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

возможно, более подходящим решением будет использовать связку из `nginx` и `fail2ban`:

- `nginx` отслеживает «нарушения» и делает запись в лог-файл.
- а `fail2ban`, как раз и специализирующийся на анализе логов, блокирует нарушителя.

неплохое описание этой связки и инструкция есть, например, на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/236859/).

Comment: fail2ban хорошее решение, но он не расчитан на режим реального времени и блокировка происходит постфактум. Также хотелось бы обойтись без iptables

Comment: не знаю, какого порядка величина задержки между появлением строки в логе и реакцией *fail2ban*-а, но предполагаю, что где-то в районе миллисекунд (fail2ban использует inotify). конечно, если такого рода задержка критична в вашей ситуации, то *fail2ban* не подойдёт. но тогда не совсем понятно пренебрежение netfilter-ом, ведь обработка проходит сразу внутри linux-а, что явно быстрее передачи и обработки пакета в user-space.

Comment: Всегда думал, что fail2ban проверяет логи по крону... А нежелание использовать фаервол диктуется исключительно ограничениями конкретного vds на количество записей. В том же конфиге nginx ограничений никаких, а адресов и подсетей очень много.

Comment: да. лимит на размер таблицы netfilter-а — это весьма «неспортивное» ограничение. с ходу приходят в голову два подхода: уменьшить время пребывания ip в «бане» и «банить» сразу сетевыми блоками («из коробки» такого конфига, вроде бы, нет, но модификация какого-нибудь образцового *action*-а [довольно тривиальна](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=724274)).

Comment: Вроде как **fail2ban** может вместо iptables использовать блокировку через hosts.deny, что меня устраивает. Буду проверять.

Comment: во-первых, там можно произвольные *shell*-команды использовать в качестве `action`. во-вторых, есть и уже готовое правило [`hostsdeny`](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/config/action.d/hostsdeny.conf).

Comment: создайте, пожалуйста, отдельный вопрос по поводу настроек `fail2ban`. я думаю, ответы на него будут полезны и другим людям.

Comment: [Отдельный вопрос по настройке fail2ban](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431984)