# Конфигурация fail2ban для обработки логов nginx

Tags: nginx

В продолжение [вопроса про nginx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431828)

Установил fail2ban, закоментил весь jail.conf и в jail.local сделал конф:

```
[DEFAULT]
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8 ХХ.ХХХ.0.0/16
bantime  = 1200
findtime = 600
maxretry = 5
backend = auto
usedns = warn
destemail = root@localhost
sendername = Fail2Ban
sender = fail2ban@localhost
banaction = hostsdeny
[nginx-404]
enabled = true
filter = nginx-404
action = hostsdeny
logpath = /var/log/nginx/error.log
findtime = 600
bantime = -7200
maxretry = 5
```

В `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-404.conf` сделал регулярку по моим логам, в месте ip адреса в регулярку поставил конструкцию `<HOST>` по аналогии с другими правилами.

Ребутнул fail2ban, в логе:

```
2015-06-25 14:50:58,950 fail2ban.server [32170]: INFO    Changed logging target to /var/log/fail2ban.log for Fail2ban v0.8.13
2015-06-25 14:50:58,951 fail2ban.jail   [32170]: INFO    Creating new jail 'nginx-404'
2015-06-25 14:50:58,984 fail2ban.jail   [32170]: INFO    Jail 'nginx-404' uses pyinotify
2015-06-25 14:50:59,004 fail2ban.jail   [32170]: INFO    Initiated 'pyinotify' backend
2015-06-25 14:50:59,006 fail2ban.filter [32170]: INFO    Added logfile = /var/log/nginx/error.log
2015-06-25 14:50:59,007 fail2ban.filter [32170]: INFO    Set maxRetry = 5
2015-06-25 14:50:59,009 fail2ban.filter [32170]: INFO    Set findtime = 600
2015-06-25 14:50:59,010 fail2ban.actions[32170]: INFO    Set banTime = -7200
2015-06-25 14:50:59,013 fail2ban.jail   [32170]: INFO    Jail 'nginx-404' started
```

Зашел с чужого ip вызвал ошибку на которую срабатывает регулярка много раз подряд... ничего.

nginx-404.conf

```
[Definition] 
failregex = ^\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ \[error\].*open\(\).*failed.*No such file or directory\), client\: <HOST>\, server.*?$ 
ignoreregex =
```

в логах соответствует записям типа

```
2015/06/25 17:39:51 [error] 2099#0: *31 open() "/var/www/site.ru/images/2015.libs.php.j" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 188.18.29.221, server: site.ru, request: "GET /images/2015.libs.php.j HTTP/1.1", host: "site.ru"
```

Еще столкнулся с проблемой, что `try_files $1 =404` пишет в лог ошибок nginx, а `return 404` в логах не появляется, не совсем понятно как однозначно маркировать директорию, чтобы она в логах была всегда, писать заведомо ложный `try_files` ?

**Добавлено**

---

Результат проверки регулярного выражения у меня выглядит так:

```
fail2ban-regex '2015/06/25 17:39:51 [error] 2099#0: *31 open() "/var/www/site.ru/images/2015.libs.php.j" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 188.18.29.221, server: site.ru, request: "GET /images/2015.libs.php.j HTTP/1.1", host: "site.ru"' 'No such file or directory.* client: <HOST>,'

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : No such file or directory.* client: <HOST>,
Use      single line : 2015/06/25 17:39:51 [error] 2099#0: *31 open() "/v...


Results
=======

Failregex: 1 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [1] No such file or directory.* client: <HOST>,
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [1] Year/Month/Day Hour:Minute:Second
`-

Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 1 matched, 0 missed
```

Comment: 1. для тестов лучше поставить `maxretry=1`, чтобы одного запроса было достаточно. 2. приведите и `nginx-404.conf`, и образцы записей из лога `nginx`, на которые `fail2ban` должен реагировать.

Comment: внесите это, пожалуйста, в вопрос: в виде комментария эта информация нечитабельна.

Comment: Добавил информацию в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

из приведённого образца:

```
2015/06/25 17:39:51 [error] 2099#0: *31 open()
"/var/www/site.ru/images/2015.libs.php.j"
failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 188.18.29.221,
server: site.ru, request: "GET /images/2015.libs.php.j HTTP/1.1", host: "site.ru"
```

видно, что для его идентификации необходимо и достаточно, по-моему, лишь наличие строки:

```
No such file or directory
```

а для самого `fail2ban`-а нужен ещё *ip*-адрес, который ограничен фрагментами `client:` и `,`.

таким образом, строка с регулярным выражением должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
failregex = No such file or directory.* client: <HOST>,
```

проверить, как `fail2ban` распарсит произвольную строку с произвольным регулярным выражением можно, воспользовавшись командой `fail2ban-regex 'строка (из лога)' 'регулярное выражение'`. вместо строки (из лога) можно указать и путь к лог-файлу (например, `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, а вместо регулярного выражения — путь к фильтру (например, `filter.d/nginx-404.conf`).

пример с актуальными данными:

```
$ fail2ban-regex '2015/06/25 17:39:51 [error] 2099#0: *31 open() "/var/www/site.ru/images/2015.libs.php.j" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 188.18.29.221, server: site.ru, request: "GET /images/2015.libs.php.j HTTP/1.1", host: "site.ru"' 'No such file or directory.* client: <HOST>,'
```

наиболее существенная (в данном случае) информация из отчёта:

```
Addresses found:
[1] 
    188.18.29.221 (Thu Jun 25 17:39:51 2015)
```

и

```
Success, the total number of match is 1
```

**в более новой версии** `fail2ban-regex` поменялся формат вывода и добавились опции. в частности, надо добавить опцию `-v`, тогда на тех же данных существенной информацией будет:

```
Failregex: 1 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [1] No such file or directory.* client: <HOST>,
|      188.18.29.221  Thu Jun 25 17:39:51 2015
```

где видно, что ip-адрес удачно извлечён, и:

```
Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 1 matched, 0 missed
```

где видно, что строка совпала с регулярным выражением: `1 matched`

---

> return 404 в логах не появляется

скорее всего, выполнение директивы `return` относится к «нормальному» завершению обработки запроса, и отчёт о её выполнении отправляется не в `error_log`, а в `access_log`.

если это верно, то можно завести отдельный `location`, в котором переопределить лог-файл, а в переменную `logpath` добавить этот файл:

```
logpath = /путь/к/файлу
          /путь/к/другому/файлу
```

а если понадобится ещё одно регулярное выражение, то можно добавить строку с ним примерно так:

```
failregex = первое регулярное выражение
            второе регулярное выражение
```

Comment: Добавил в вопрос как выглядит результат проверки регулярки у меня (скопипастил прямо из вашего сообщения).  Мне по выводу не понятно до конца, но по факту ни один вариант регулярки (если в них дело) не работает, в `hosts.deny` новых строк нет...

Comment: В  `hostsdeny.conf` кстати строка бана выглядит так `actionban = IP=<ip> &&
            printf %%b "<daemon_list>: $IP\n" >> <file>`, может вместо `<HOST>` нужно писать в регулярке `<ip>` ?

Comment: *ни один вариант регулярки не работает* — тут как обычно: откуда установлен пакет, какой версии?

Comment: понятно, в более новой версии `fail2ban` несколько изменили формат вывода и опций добавили. в частности, `-v`: при её использовании показывает «выловленный» ip-адрес. сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: *ни один вариант регулярки не работает* — вы учитываете, что нужно `maxretry` раз повторить попытку с одного и того же ip, причём в течение `findtime` секунд. а вообще проанализируйте сам лог с помощью `fail2ban-regex`, указав путь к нему первым параметром.

Comment: *может вместо <HOST> нужно писать в регулярке <ip> ?* — нет. в регулярное выражение вместо `<HOST>` подставляется кусочек регулярного выражения, «вылавливающего» ip-адрес **или** dns-имя.

Comment: _откуда установлен пакет, какой версии?_                                Как видно в логе старта в вопросе **Fail2ban v0.8.13** это штатный пакет в самых свежих репозиториях Дебиан. Что касается логов, я просто вручную вставляю в лог портянку "валидных" запросов, чтобы наверняка и рестартую нужные сервисы. Лог анализировал, совпадения находит.

Comment: *вручную вставляю* — а время вы при этом меняете на актуальное? ведь «`findtime` секунд» отсчитывается от текущего времени. и более старые записи просто игнорируются.

Comment: Да конечно. Вот нагенерил еще вручную сейчас ошибок, вижу как процесс fail2ban-server отрабатывает, а результата нет. Работает от рута, права на запись значит есть, в чем проблема не пойму...

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25229/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-a-off).

Comment: В общем шаманским путем удаления, установки новой версии и накатывания старой поверх, все завелось и заработало с текущими конфигами.

Comment: поздравляю! если мой [ответ на первоначальный вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431829/178576) тоже оказался полезен, сделайте об этом отметку, пожалуйста.